# How can I save item output in macro in zabbix

Tags: zabbix

how can I save item's output in macro and use it in another item ?
i mean reguler item not LLD .
for example : I want to get some port app dynamicly and check tcp conection

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use case but most of the times this would be solved by making a port discovery item and generate net.tcp.listen or net.tcp.port items for them
[Zabbix agent](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent)

Items are static and don’t contain variables. This is were low level discovery shows it’s value. Lld rules contain macros like #PORT that will be used to generate item[s] using the discovered #PORT value, one for each item.

A nice explanation and example about dynamic tcp port monitoring can be found in this [blog](https://blog.zabbix.com/automatic-tcp-port-monitoring/11652/)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: thanks  ik_zelf . that's the way